# Properly pickling and unpickling proxy objects in Python (multiprocessing)? "ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused while unpickling"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle, python-multiprocessing, multiprocessing-manager

I am getting "ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused" while doing pickle.load()

What does than actually mean? How do I properly unpickle such object? I know that the object I am trying to unpickle contains some useful data but I can't get to it.

I am passing this object to threads and subprocesses

```
obj = {
  'var1': multiprocessing.Manager().Queue(), 
  'var2': 'some data'
}
```

What an I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `pickle.dump(obj,path)` to serialize obj, and if this `obj` contained some multiprocessing related stuff, such as pool, dict, when using `pickle.load(...)` to deserialize dumped file, you will get this error

Comment: Thank you. I guess I would just need to find the other way of extracting values from that "special" objects...